# How to show the data related to an ID instead of the ID?

Tags: database, delphi, dbgrid

In summary, I have a database (Access) with 4 related tables, as seen in the picture:

[image]

In Delphi, I have a `TDBGrid` that shows the data from the "resultas" table (using `TADOTable`), as seen here:

[image]

As you can see, the field for the test id shows numbers (id of the test). What I want is to show the test name instead of that number. Or, can I add a field (in Delphi) that shows the name of the test related to the id (a calculated field, maybe)?

Comment: This is a good introduction to accessing database data from a Delphi app: https://www.thoughtco.com/beginners-guide-to-delphi-1057714

Comment: Use a ``TADOQuery`` instead of a ``TADOTable``, then you can use the necessary fields from both tables and link them together with e.g. a(n) (inner) join

Comment: thank you all for your answers. Im a beginner in delphi, and programing in general. I just wanted a simple way do display data in a field that is related to another in another table. I did try using joind query but i have no idea how to make the result of a select query editable. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Lookup field defined in TADOTable component which is responsible for "Resultas" table. [Defining a Lookup Field](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Defining_a_Lookup_Field)

Keep in mind that big datasets could result to poor performance. The correct way is to use SELECTs with JOINs in TADOQuery.

Comment: Thx for you answer. I'll do my research on the lookup field as you suggested. About using select with a joined quey, i stumbled upon a problem: editing or deleting a data from the result of the query, as i understand it the result posted is just read only no? if there is a way to edit the data returned through a select query please enlighten me. Thanx and best regards

Comment: Editing results of SELECTs with joins is not very common, it is possible, but I do not recommend it. If you need to edit the results grid - the easiest option is Lookup fields.

Comment: Thank you. lookup fields is what i needed. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`TDBGrid` has an [`OnDrawColumnCell`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) event.  You can custom-drawn any cell to look however you want.

Or, you could simply access the `TADOTable`'s `TField` object for the `ID_Test` field, and assign a handler to its [`OnGetText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.OnGetText) event to return the `TField.DisplayText` value of the table's `Nom_Test` field.

Comment: Or you could learn SQL and use a join.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I'll try it. Best regards